# MySQL events SELECT between 2 date

Tags: mysql, sql, select, between

I have a two column with date (from, to) in date format (Y-m-d), and I need MySQL SELECT which returns a correct value:

eg. I have same events:

```
 1. 2015-07-10 to: 2015-07-25
 2. 2015-07-21 to: 2015-07-24
 3. 2015-07-19 to: 2015-08-01
 4. 2015-07-29 to: 2015-08-05
 5. 2015-08-05 to: 2015-08-06
 6. 2015-08-10 to: 2015-08-10
```

and I need all events which is between 2015-07-11 and 2015-07-21.

```
**expected results:** 
*1,2,3*
```

Thank you!

Comment: use between function

Comment: His problem is ID 1. Since from is not between and to isn't between, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ID 2, ID 3 you can check with "Between". For ID 1 you have to check if:

1. Is From lower/equal than my start point?
2. Is To higher/equal than my end point?

With this two questions you ensure it is within your Range.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/642fb7/1

Here you got an example. :)